# Finding Longitude and Latitude using SPARQL

Tags: geolocation, sparql, endpoint, dbpedia, geo

I have an OWL ontology with quite a few places: cities, nations, states, districts, and specific sites such as a business or church. I want to use SPARQL to query some external data source (I assume a SPARQL endpoint), find the matching place and copy the long and lat data to my ontology. My ontology deals with the Covid pandemic and is called CODO. So I've tried things like:

```
    PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
    PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> 
    PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
    PREFIX codo: <http://www.isibang.ac.in/ns/codo#>
    PREFIX geo: <http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#> 
    PREFIX dbo: <http://live.dbpedia.org/> 
    INSERT  {?c codo:long ?long.
             ?c  codo:lat ?lat.} 
     WHERE {?c a codo:City. 
            ?c rdfs:label ?l. 
            ?dbpc a dbo:City. 
            ?dbpc rdfs:label ?l.    
            ?dbpc geo:long ?long.
            ?dbpc geo:lat ?lat.}
```

I got those specific namespaces from examples I found on the web. I have no preference as to where I get the data, Geonames, DBpedia, doesn't matter. I think part of the problem is I'm not exactly clear about when/how to use the SERVICE and/or FROM keywords.

Comment: for remote endpoints you always use the `SERVICE` keyword. `FROM` is basically used to add graphs to the default graph used during query evaluation. The `SERVICE` keyword just wraps the graph pattern you need from the remote endpoint, e.g. `construct {?c geo:long ?long ; geo:lat ?lat } where {?c a codo:City ; rdfs:label ?l. SERVICE <http://dbpedia.org/sparql> {?s a dbo:City; rdfs:label ?l ; geo:lat ?lat ; geo:long ?long}}` - for `INSERT` query it works the same way

Comment: -  note, implementation of the `SERVICE` clause is sometimes vague, i.e. it's not clear if data from the "outer" query is inlined or not - but this is obviously necessary to avoid getting all data and doing the join locally. With Apache Jena if will run one remote query per local binding for example. Just keep this in mind, a remote service might block if too many request happen in a short time from the same IP address.

Comment: An alternative for your task could be to i) simply download the DBpedia lat/long data or ii) write a query where you load just the data for your local cities, i.e. `CONSTRUCT{?l geo:long ?long ; geo:lat ?lat.} WHERE {VALUES ?l {"city1label" "city2label" ... "citynlabel"} ?c a dbo:City ; rdfs:label ?l ; geo:long ?long ; geo:lat ?lat.}` - this would result in one possible large query but should be more efficient (don't forget language tags when comparing labels!)

Comment: @UninformedUser Thanks a lot for the suggestions. That helps. I like the idea of just downloading the DBpedia data but I would rather not load the data for our cities because if I'm understanding your suggestion there it means listing every city (also state, district, nation, etc.) and we have a lot and will be adding more as we extend our work beyond India.

Comment: I see. Ok, then you should go with federated queries via the `SERVICE` keyword. The `CONSTRUCT` query in my first comment is just a sketch but at least it works - tested it with Apache Jena from commandline and some dummy data.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the problem. With the query engine I'm using (Gruff in Allegrograph from Franz Inc.) I don't even need to use the SERVICE keyword, all I need to do is connect to the endpoint using one of the File options in Gruff. I was doing that already but I was using the wrong IRI for the places in DBpedia.  The following works now:

```
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/> 
PREFIX geo: <http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#> 
SELECT ?City ?long ?lat where {?City a dbo:City; geo:lat ?lat ; geo:long ?long} 
limit 200
```

Now that this is working, it should be straight forward to link to places in our ontology and copy over the needed data. Thanks to UninformedUser and my colleague Biswanath_Dutta for helping me figure this out.